# boost asio SSL server error: called a function you should not call

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, boost, boost-asio

I am using the [example from boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/server.cpp) with three minor differences:

1. I use threads to process `io_service`
2. I have limited the protocol to `> TLS v1.1`
3. There is no password callback, because the cert key has no password

The threads simply process various connections in parallel

```
void server::start()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < thread_pool_size_; i++) {
        threads_.push_back(std::thread([&]() {
            io_service_.run();
        }));
    }
    for (auto & t : threads_) { 
        t.join();
    }
}
```

The context arguments are:

```
ctx.set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
               |boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
               |boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3
               |boost::asio::ssl::context::no_tlsv1
               |boost::asio::ssl::context::no_tlsv1_1
               |boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
```

Apart from that, a `connection` class controls internally a `ssl_socket`,
which follows the following callback chain:

`ctor
  -> start
    -> async_handshake
      -> read_header
        -> async_read_until
          -> process_header
            ...`

If I replace the SSL socket with a plaintext socket `ip::tcp::socket` then everything works fine.
When using the SSL socket, I keep getting `called a function you should not call`.

GDB shows that this originates from `async_handshake`. After reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828066/how-to-decipher-a-boost-asio-ssl-error-code) I managed to obtain the error code:

`(20,197,66) error:140C5042:SSL routines:ssl_undefined_function:called a function you should not call`.

I'm using Boost 1.58 on Ubuntu 16.04.
Any help as to why this is happening, what might be causing it, or what I could possibly have done wrong?

If it matters, I am testing with `curl` using the `-insecure` flag.

## EDIT

Did try without the restrictive protocol flags, and by setting a password callback - problem still persists.

Comment: What is the relevance of the curl testing?

Comment: @sehe it is the client. I was hoping it was ignoring the self signed certificate, but this seems to trigger regardless of protocol or certificate

Comment: Ok. That's purely client side, so it makes no difference. (Never mind about the "server" it was hidden in the title :))

Comment: My gut says you need to provide the password callback. Have you tried adding one? Might be just the case of "blank password" !=/== "no password" (Apple knows all about that now)

Comment: @sehe just tried it, didn't change anything :-(

Comment: Do you have the code in a repo/shareable? I want to have a look but I'm not feeling well enough to retrace your steps from the example app

Comment: @sehe I'm honored and I would not mind to share but this is a private repo. I can copy paste the important bits to a new repo if needed, since I am not certain that I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that the following line triggers the problem:

```
context_(io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12_client)
```

I should have paid more attention to my code (copy-paste is the root of all evil):
The offending line was in the `context` constructor:

```
ctx_(io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12_client)
```

I've replaced with the `server` version:

```
context_(io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12_server)
```

The [full list is hidden](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp) in the implementation header of boost.
Insert *big facepalm here* :-)